# How to count scrolled pixels to the left/right with jQuery within a Drupal7 page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, scroll, scrolltop

With

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log($(this).scrollTop());

});
```

You can count the pixels you are scrolling up or down. But how could I count the scrolling from left to right?

I could imagine to watch the offset of a hidden fixed element, but isn't there another way like the one above?

edit: problem is that when using Drupal you need to encapsulate your jquery inside

```
jQuery(function($) {...
```

I tried the solution [i found here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1838-Wrapping-The-Window-Object-In-A-jQuery-Wrapper.htm) where I scoped the window object to

```
var thisWindow = window;
```

outside the jQuery-capsule, but it crashed my site and did not work.

EDIT2: o.k. - maybe it is also important to notice that may #main-DIV is set to 'overflow-y: hidden;' and its child .region.content-DIV is set to 'overflow-x: scroll;'

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/

Comment: hey, that was fast - but how could I implement it? its not workin on the window element inside the scroll listener.

Comment: Beats me, I haven't seen your HTML yet. But http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/7mEVb/ seems to work fine.

Comment: ok, I see. strange. I tried that and in my complex page setup it is not working out of the box. Seems that I have to find out why... thanx!

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I needed to directly talk to the scrolling dif. sounds logic...

```
$('#main .region-content').scroll(function() {
    console.log($('#a-special-div-id').offset().left);
});
```

did the trick. enough for a workaround.
thnx for the pushing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scrollLeft()` function. [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/)